# How to suppress unique key checking while sql insert

Tags: mysql

I got a MySQL database with some tables.

In one of these tables i want to insert by a SQL script some new rows.

Unfortunately i have to insert in two columns an empty string and the two columns are part of an unique key for that table.

So i tried to set UNIQUE_CHECKS before and after the insert, but i'm getting errors because of duplicate entries.

Here is the definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changedBy` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changeDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the INSERT statement which causes error:

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
INSERT INTO `Table_A`
(`name`, `number`, `changedBy`, `changeDate`)
SELECT DISTINCT '', 'myUser', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Table_A
AND id NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM Table_A
);
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
```

As You can see, i'm using UNIQUE_CHECKS.

But as i said this doesn't work properly.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Patrick

Comment: Why it should make sence to insert keys with dupplicate key in a table?

Comment: Hello Jens. It's because we need to add a component type with no name to each component kind which does not have any component type of that kind. Normally - while administrating component types - the user shall not be able to add a component type with a name which already exists.

Comment: So sounds like you have to remove the unique key constraint. *the user shall not be able to add a component type with a name which already exists* should be checked in your Business logic

Comment: Hello Jens. I tried that too. I'm able to remove the index and after the insert i re-added it. Unfortunately in that case i could just restore it without unique.

Comment: **You can't** insert non unique data to a column with unique contraint. Also you can not add a unique contraint on column with non unique data

Comment: Thank You Jens. I will think about that together with my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Switching off Unique Keys for the insert operation doesn't indicate that it will check uniqueness only for the operations that happen after you switch it on again. It just means that database will not waste time to check the constraint during the time it is switch off but it will check the constraint when you switch it on again.

What it measn is that you nead to ensure that column has unique value in a columns with Unique Keys before you can turn it on. Which you don't do.

If you want to maintain Uniqueness somehow for new records you insert after some point in time you would need to create trigger and manually check the new records against already existing data. The same possibly goes for updates. But I don't recommend it - you should probably redesign data so either the Unique Key is not there or the data is truly unique for all the records there are and will be.

Comment: Thank You nimdil. I will think about that together with my colleagues.

Comment: I am not able to go wild and propose them a data model today but it does sound like the underlying problem is an incorrectly designed data model that has gotten them into this situation in the first place.